# PHP fixed isset issue but it says i cannot use it

Tags: php

i managed to remove my undefined index issue but this new error pops out:

> Fatal error: Cannot use `isset()` on the result of an expression (you
>   can use "null !== expression" instead) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mwc_canuto\cms\orders.php on line 106

this is the line:

```
if (isset($rowOrder['expirationdate'] >  date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), ($rowOrder['scheduled'] || $rowOrder['used']) == 1))
```

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory here. As it says `isset` cannot be used on an expression, and gives you what you can use instead being `null !== expression`.

Comment: "isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL" - http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Does `$rowOrder['expirationdate'] >  date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` actual work as expected? I'd think you'd need to convert both to their epoch (or use `time()` for the current time).

Comment: my whole if condition worked, tested it out, its just that fatal error problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `isset()` on the result of an expression. For your case, you can restructure your code like below.

```
if( isset($rowOrder['expirationdate']) && ($rowOrder['expirationdate'] > date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) && ($rowOrder['scheduled'] || $rowOrder['used']) )
```

Answer (score 1):

The [isset()](https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/isset.php) function is used to check whether a variable is set or not, in your case you're using isset() function to check a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Something is going wrong in your `if` condition.

1. when use `isset` then you can not use with condition but `isset` is using to check whether variable is set or not and you have complete brace also. `isset($var)`.
2. When you can use `if` condition you can not use `,` to separate two conditions. For that you write `||` between two conditions.

So from these rule you can write `if` condition like this:

```
if (isset($rowOrder['expirationdate']) && ($rowOrder['expirationdate'] >  date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))  ||  ($rowOrder['scheduled'] || $rowOrder['used']) == 1))
```